# Javascript - How do I change attribute of each generated textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I Am currently working on a small project but tried everything and can't come up with a solution to my problem. I'm working on a to do list and using javascript to generate textboxes with a button that stores its value. The Button generates a textbox and 3 additional buttons (1 delete task button (red), 1 change its value button (yellow) and 1 completed button (green) which moves the task to a new list and generates 2 additional buttons delete task and the yellow button which does the same as preview). The problem is that when generating x amount of textboxes only the first textbox will work when changing its value (clicking on yellow button), how can I make it so each button works individually for respective textbox.

The same problem remains when clicking on the green button (completed button) in which only the first textbox in the list will display its value.

```js
const syssla = document.querySelector("#min-syssla");
let firstbutton = document.querySelector(".firstbutton");
const ullist = document.querySelector(".unorderedlist");
const listdone = document.querySelector(".list-done");

firstbutton.addEventListener("click", task);

function task(event) {
  const tododiv = document.createElement("div");
  tododiv.classList.add("todo");

  const list = document.createElement('li');
  list.classList.add('todo-item');
  tododiv.appendChild(list);

  const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
  completedButton.innerText = "Färdig";
  completedButton.classList.add("complete_btn");
  list.appendChild(completedButton);

  const editButton = document.createElement('button');
  editButton.innerText = "Ändra";
  editButton.classList.add("edit_btn");
  list.appendChild(editButton);

  const eraseButton = document.createElement('button');
  eraseButton.innerText = "Radera";
  eraseButton.classList.add("erase_btn");
  list.appendChild(eraseButton);

  var textinput = document.createElement("input");
  textinput.type = "text";
  textinput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  textinput.classList.add("newbox");
  list.appendChild(textinput);
  textinput.value = syssla.value;

  ullist.appendChild(tododiv);

  firstbutton.value = "";

  event.preventDefault();
}

ullist.addEventListener('click', deletecheckbox);

function deletecheckbox(e) {
  let item = e.target;
  if (item.classList[0] === 'erase_btn') {
    const make = item.parentElement;
    make.remove();
  }

  if (item.classList[0] === 'complete_btn') {
    const radera1 = item.parentElement;
    let completedButton = document.querySelector(".complete_btn");

    const tododiv2 = document.createElement("div");
    tododiv2.classList.add("todo2");

    const list2 = document.createElement('li');
    list2.classList.add('todo-item2');
    tododiv2.appendChild(list2);

    const editButton1 = document.createElement('button');
    editButton1.innerText = "Ändra";
    editButton1.classList.add("edit_btn1");
    list2.appendChild(editButton1);

    const eraseButton1 = document.createElement('button');
    eraseButton1.innerText = "Radera";
    eraseButton1.classList.add("erase_btn1");
    list2.appendChild(eraseButton1);

    let textinput2 = document.createElement("input");
    textinput2.type = "text";
    textinput2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    textinput2.classList.add("newbox2");
    list2.appendChild(textinput2);

    listdone.appendChild(tododiv2);

    textinput = document.querySelector(".newbox");

    textinput2.value = textinput.value;

    radera1.remove();
  }

  editButton = document.querySelector(".edit_btn");
  editButton.addEventListener('click', change());

  function change() {
    textinput = document.querySelector(".newbox");

    if (item.classList[0] === "edit_btn") {
      if (textinput.disabled === true) {
        textinput.removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else if (textinput.disabled === false) {
        textinput.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    }
  }
}

listdone.addEventListener('click', donebox);

function donebox(ev) {
  let item1 = ev.target;
  if (item1.classList[0] === 'erase_btn1') {
    const eraser = item1.parentElement;
    eraser.remove();
  }

  if (item1.classList[0] === 'edit_btn1') {
    textinput2 = document.querySelector(".newbox2");
    if (textinput2.disabled === true) {
      textinput2.removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else if (textinput2.disabled === false) {
      textinput2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px white;
  background-color: rgb(48, 49, 51, 0.7);
  opacity: 1;
}

#min-syssla {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 25px;
  width: 170px;
}

#wrapper-box {
  border: 1px black;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, lightblue, blue 90%);
  border: 3px outset blue;
  border-top-left-radius: 5%;
  border-top-right-radius: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 37.5%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

.firstbutton {
  position: relative;
  left: 270px;
  bottom: 18px;
  border: 1px ridge blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 30px;
}

.todo-item {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.complete_btn {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.complete_btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(86, 234, 7, 0.9);
}

.erase_btn {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 22px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.erase_btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 84, 84, 0.9);
}

.edit_btn {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: black;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.edit_btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(213, 219, 46, 0.9);
}

.newbox {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px ridge darkorange;
  padding: 5px;
}

.erase_btn1 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.erase_btn1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 84, 84, 0.9);
}

.edit_btn1 {
  margin-right: 75px;
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  color: black;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.edit_btn1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(213, 219, 46, 0.9);
}

.newbox2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px ridge greenyellow;
}

.todo-item2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Kunskapskontroll</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Mina Sysslor</h1>
  <div id="wrapper-box">
    <input type="text" id="min-syssla" placeholder="Min syssla" name="min-syssla"><br><br><br>
    <button class="firstbutton" type="submit">Lägg till</button>
    <div class="syssla-container">
      <h2>Att göra</h2>
      <ul class="unorderedlist"></ul>
      <h2>Färdiga</h2>
      <ul class="list-done"></ul>
    </div>
```

I haven't tried much because I have no clue of how to manage to change the attribute for every new textbox.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the problem, but instead of testing `item.classList[0]`, use `item.classList.includes()`. That way the order of the classes doesn't matter.

Comment: You're calling `change()` immediately here: `editButton.addEventListener('click', change());` Remove the `()` so it's called when the click happens.

Comment: `editButton.addEventListener('click', change());` This only adds the event listener to the first edit button, and you keep adding another listener every time you create a task. You should use event delegation for this button just like the other buttons.

Comment: I tried to remove the () in change and now only the first yellow button works on the first textbox, but I dont understand why the delete button works fine on everything but the yellow and green button doesnt work on its textboxes.